# REGEXP_LIKE to matchtwo words in a sentence in Oracle 11g

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

sentence :"STANDARD domain WARNING encountered in the PROCESS"

I want to identify all the sentences which have the words STANDARD and WARNING in it using REGEXP_LIKE. Also the search has to be case insensitive.

I would want to replace the following code with REGEXP_LIKE:

```
Select * from table where upper(sentence) like 'STANDARD%WARNING%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `'i'` match parameter for case insensitivity:

```
Select * from table where REGEXP_LIKE (sentence, '\bstandard(?=\b).*\bwarning\b', 'i')
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is powerful but not so good with performance.
Try this -

```
Select * from table 
 where upper(sentence) like '%STANDARD%' or
       upper(sentence) like '%WARNING%'
```

Easy to read and serve the purpose.